# List text field dependent of text field

Tags: entities

In my user edit form I want to add a text field where it asks name of class and I want to add other field List text type and it will display the grade for example:

Math        Grade 7
Now the issue is that teacher can add more than 1 class so and the option field I set unlimited elemts but it doesn't work properly because also I need to add element in List text.

I want to achive this:

Math   Grade 7
Bio    Grade 5

Add class

Issue:

Math Bio
Grade 7 Grade 5

one is not depending of other, please Help!!

Comment: are you using field collection module or any other modle to bundle uo the two different fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module to achieve this.

Using this module you can create group of field, such as class and grade in one collection. Also you can set 'Number of values' to unlimited for field.

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I did know that it module exist, thank you I will check it.